# TF 2.0 while_loop and parallel_iterations

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing

I am trying to use `tf.while_loop` to run loops in parallel. However, in the following toy examples,loops don't appear to be running in parallel.

```
iteration = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 1000)
def print_fun(iteration):
    print(f"This is iteration {iteration}")
    iteration+=1
    return (iteration,)
r = tf.while_loop(c, print_fun, [iteration], parallel_iterations=10)
```

Or

```
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 1000)
b = lambda i: (tf.add(i, 1),)
r = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
```

What is preventing the `tf.while_loop` from parallelizing the loop?

In addition, if anyone who maintain the Tensorflow documentation see this page, he/she should fix the bug in the first example. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18257).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`parallel_iterations` doesn't mean anything when running in eager mode, but you can always use `tf.function` decorator and gain significant speedups. This can be seen in this picture: [running times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz3GL.png)

You can wrap your `tf.while_loop` with `tf.function` like this

```
@tf.function
def run_graph():
    iteration = tf.constant(0)
    r = tf.while_loop(c, print_fun, [iteration], parallel_iterations=4)
```

and then call `run_graph` when required.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand how the function works better. May I ask an additional question? Why does TF has its own while loop in the first place? Is it just to provide an option to parallelize the loop? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Srihari, what happens if you change `parallel_iterations=4` by `parallel_iterations=1`? I have the feeling that the numebers you show in the image above do not change. At least they don't change for me (TF2.3). Do you know why?