# tf.function and tf.while loop in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to parallelize loop using `tf.while_loop`. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299060/tf-2-0-while-loop-and-parallel-iterations), the `parallel_iterations` argument doesn't make a difference in the eager mode. So I attempted to wrap `tf.while_loop` with `tf.function`. However, after adding the decorator,the behavior of the iteration variable changes.

For example, this piece of code works.

```
result = np.zeros(10)
iteration = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 10)
def print_fun(iteration):
    result[iteration] = iteration
    iteration += 1
    return (iteration,)
tf.while_loop(c, print_fun, [iteration])
```

If I add the decorator, bug occurs.

```
result = np.zeros(10)
iteration = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 10)
def print_fun(iteration):
    result[iteration] = iteration
    iteration += 1
    return (iteration,)

@tf.function
def run_graph():
    iteration = tf.constant(0)
    tf.while_loop(c, print_fun, [iteration])

run_graph()
```

From my debugging process, I found that variable `iteration` changes from a tensor  to a placeholder. Why is that? How should I modify the code to eliminate the bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The code in your first snippet (the one without the `@tf.function`) takes advantage of TensorFlow 2's eager execution to manipulate a numpy array (i.e., your outer `iteration` object) directly. With `@tf.function`, this doesn't work because @tf.function tries to compile your code into a tf.Graph, which cannot operate on a numpy array directly (it can only process tensorflow tensors). To get around this issue, use a tf.Variable and keep assigning value into its slices.

With `@tf.function`, what you are trying to do is actually achievable with simpler code, by taking advantage of `@tf.function`'s automatic Python-to-graph transformation feature (known as AutoGraph). You just write a normal Python while loop (using `tf.less()` in lieu of the `<` operator), and the while loop will be compiled by AutoGraph into a tf.while_loop under the hood.

The code looks something like:

```py
result = tf.Variable(np.zeros([10], dtype=np.int32))

@tf.function
def run_graph():
  i = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
  while tf.less(i, 10):
    result[i].assign(i)  # Performance may require tuning here.
    i += 1

run_graph()
print(result.read_value())
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Without calling `tf.while_loop`, is there a way to set up multiple iterations running in parallel? The reason I tried to use `tf.while_loop` is that I would like to parallelize the loop while saving the result of each iteration.

Comment: Good question. In the above code, you can add the following line at the end to inspect the structure of the resulting tf.Graph: `print(run_graph.get_concrete_function().graph.as_graph_def())`. In there, you can see While op's parellel_iterations attribute is already set to 10 (the default value). You can also explore the undocumented and relatively new `tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options() API`. See example at:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/lang/directives.py#L64

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will take a look them first. I started with TF 2.0 and had little knowledge about TF 1.0.